# Auto-Attendant on Cisco CUC

Tags: cisco, voip, voice

I'm trying to apply an auto-attendant on a CUC, where the voice message will be just played for one time and stops, and if the caller didn't dial anything the call would hangup after 10 sec.

I know that you can hangup it after one time playing directly but I'm interested in setting a time after this voice message plays.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem using the Unity Connection Audio Text Manger , it worked fine now.

Its also much better than using the Media Master if you want to upload a new audio file to the for your greeting message.